# Are questions about leather-working on topic?

Tags: discussion

So, I got a bit hooked up with re-enactment/LARP recently. Part of the fun for me is the crafting, leatherworking and sewing.

I found an image of a piece of leather armour with I would love to create for myself, but I have no real idea how to do so. Would a question on how a given piece of clothing/armour was created be on topic at Arts&Crafts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we have some questions about leather and some about costume design. Go for it!

Just make sure your question is specific and detailed enough that it is answerable :) "How do I make this" isn't a great question, while "What materials and tools do I need?" is better. And feel to keep asking new questions if you get stumped at any part of the process!

Comment: Thanks for the info, then I'll proceed once I have enough time to back the question up with deeds.